# Meteor isn't working on Windows7 64 bit

Tags: node.js, meteor, fibers

I am just trying out Meteor on my Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit box. I installed it via MSI from http://win.meteor.com, rebooted the machine and in command prompt (administrator), did the following:

> cd /d c:\var
>   meteor create testapp
>   (absolutely no response on console)

Then I insured that node.exe is working. I created a test.js with basic hello world example and it worked (I browsed to the localhost:xxx and was greeted).

> node test.js

Then I went right into the meteor.js code, and upon encountering     process.stderr.write inside fiber(...), I decided to call the same at the beginning of the file outside fiber.
    process.stderr.write("outside fiber");
(this message got printed
; confirmed that there is a problem with fibers)

Now upon research, I stumble upon

> npm test fibers
>   (output: Error: Test `already-running.js` failed.
>   code: -1073741819  ....)

Then I did

> npm remove fibers
>   npm install fibers

However, the error with test fiber continues so does the absolute no-output from meteor command.

could anybody help? I'm out of options and this is my first attempt at meteor/nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered an issue with node fibers (on windows) and have a tentative fix - at least it fixed the problem for me, and I would be interested to see if that also fixes it for others.

Ultimately the problem was apparently sudden death due stack overflow and access violation. The root cause however was that the thread locals were not correctly being switched on a fiber switch.

Please see https://github.com/TomWij/meteor/issues/66#issuecomment-15994548 for details.

See related Stack Overflow question: [Meteor on Windows: meteor command outputs nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15425953/1129543)

Answer (score -1):

You need to know that, by now, meteor dont officially support windows.
I can recommend you to try using virtualbox and a linux distro in a virtual machine.

Comment: I didn't miss it, meteor don't **officially** support windows

Comment: You should cite your references, https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Supported-Platforms

Comment: OK, you found the reference, but I'm still rigth: meteor don't officially support windows.

Comment: It's not a matter of 'right' or 'wrong' so much as a matter of useful advice, and complete information.  It's better to explain what it means that windows support is an unofficial preview (and cite the reference) and then talk about the options to either fix the issue (by seeking support from the meteor windows community) or routing around the issue by using a supported platform as you suggest.  You could improve your answer by explaining the why and how.  Links to virtual box and suggestions about which distro to use would help the OP and people like him.