# Meteor on Windows: meteor command outputs nothing

Tags: meteor

I installed the MSI file from win.meteor.com

I reboot the computer, and open up CMD and type `meteor create app` but nothing happens. It doesn't say the command was undefined, so I don't know what's wrong here.

I am using windows 7 64-bit home.

Comment: Did setting the env path solve the problem?

Comment: I am giving that a shot right now....if this doesn't work I guess I have to setup virtualbox

Comment: Try navigating to the bin directory where `meteor` is available and execute the command

Comment: yup, tried both, still same thing. as soon as I run it, it just exits.

Comment: Could you run `node -v` in your command prompt? what does it say

Comment: node -v gives me v0.8.18

Comment: cmonnnnnn nobody has a solution??!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered an issue with node fibers (on windows) and have a tentative fix - at least it fixed the problem for me, and I would be interested to see if that also fixes it for others.

Ultimately the problem was apparently sudden death due stack overflow and access violation. The root cause however was that the thread locals were not correctly being switched on a fiber switch.

Answer (score 1):

you should check the environment path

add Meteor root directory to PATH
like this

> PATH: ...;d:\Meteor;d:\Meteor\bin
>
> METEOR_PATH: d:\Meteor
>
> NODE_PATH: d:\Meteor\lib\node_modules

Comment: I have set it up like this but still same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too..

```
METEOR_PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\
NODE_PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules
PATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware vSphere CLI\Perl\site\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware vSphere CLI\Perl\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2;C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\bin
```

When you I run the meteor command, it does open meteor.js in node (if I add console.log('xxx') to meteor.js I see output), but the script finishes with no output.